# Functional equations vs. Mathematical ZFC models

Tags: functional-equations, integro-differential-equations

Is the solutions of a functional equation uniquely determined by ZFC axioms, or could it requires adittional axioms?

I refer to differential and integro-differential equations principally

Comment: You might want to expand the question a bit via an [edit].

Comment: I hope you improve this question, as I think it is potentially interesting - but currently, it is just too unclear.

Answer (score 3):

The question doesn't really make sense. Our physical equations are simply equations - nothing more - and they are a *model* of the world, not the world itself. It just doesn't make sense to ask whether non-mathematical results are independent of the mathematical model: it's like asking whether the question of "what did I last eat?" is independent of ZFC.

Usually we say a statement is *independent of ZFC* if there is a model of ZFC in which the axiom is true, and a model in which it is false. OK, let's try and ask whether the Schrödinger equation (SE)'s truth is independent of ZFC. Well, is there a model of ZFC in which the SE is true? Er… I don't know how to answer that. It's like asking whether there's a model of ZFC in which I am five years old. It's not clear that I even *exist* as an entity in ZFC.

As another angle on your question, it is possible to construct much of mathematics - including real analysis - in systems other than ZFC. Real analysis can be developed using much weaker choice principles than the full power of the Axiom of Choice; and I seem to recall that the real numbers may be constructed in New Foundations (which is very much not ZFC). Additionally, you can relax quite a lot of the Axiom of Replacement, because real analysis occurs at a very shallow level of the von Neumann hierarchy. Therefore, you don't have to use ZFC if you want to state the Schrödinger equation.

Of course, just stating the SE doesn't help you at all in saying things about the real world. If you want to say things about the real world, you need to state the SE *and then make and test predictions* about your model. ZFC can't help you there.

Comment: Sorry, I can´t understand you. All the space sets in physical space have volume. It depends from the choice axiom. But the choice axioms it is neccesary for Hilbert Space, it is antiintuitivyty  but there are regions of space without volume. There is no transcendent  for physics if we consider point particles. In this case the physics is independent, but in another questions? I don´t understand twhen you say that the question have no sense

Comment: Hilbert spaces are an abstraction, a model which doesn't necessarily correspond to the real world. "All space sets in physical space…" how do you know sets even exist in the real world? Certainly it seems consistent to define volume in space, but it's ultimately just a model and we don't know whether it's truly 100% accurate. (Aside from anything else, space might be quantised.)

Comment: Well, it is ok that the actual equation for physics (quantum field theory+reativity) can´t be the ultimate equation s(only a very very good aproxximation relativity in macrocospic physics and QFT in microscopic (when macroscopic results observable of course ). Actually, this conclussion can be purelly mathematical. QFT in a curved space time is not renormalizable (the physics measurements predicted measures are some of them infinitys  of the closed real line). It have no sense. There are many diffents ways treatin to create a new theory that confirms the previous results from QFT and GR).

Comment: You still seem to be confused about the difference between a model of the world, and the world itself.

Comment: continuation: But it is possible that really exists a real true system of equations descripting the real laws of the universe. My question is about these plausible final equation. I suppose that this final law includes concepts and phormulas from ZFC. But some concepts of ZFC are not absolute, are not indepent from adittional axioms for ZFC. I would like if it is possible that it depends from adittional axioms and I want to know if SE and GR Equations intended in a pure formal mathematical sense are dependent only from ZFC. Dio you feel my question have sense now??

Comment: And about an hipotetical final theory, could it be that it could depend of adittional axioms for ZFC or did you think there are a good argument to think that I wouldn´t problematic.

Comment: There can be no answer to that question until we know exactly what the laws of reality are. It's pointless to speculate about whether we live in a space which is exactly or not, when we don't have strong evidence one way or the other. By the way, if we discover that there is some fact about the universe which is independent of ZFC, then we will know for sure that ZFC is the wrong set theory for maths.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: Your last comment honestly makes no sense. If ZFC correctly models some aspect of the universe, then Con(ZFC) is true about the universe, but we already know that it is independent of ZFC, which by your comment implies that ZFC is the wrong set theory for math.

Comment: @user21820 But what if ZFC correctly models no aspects of the universe? It might be consistent but simply fail to apply to the universe.

Comment: @PatrickStevens: I didn't exclude that possibility. I was saying that your comment makes no sense because it implies that ZFC is in **all cases** the wrong set theory for math, where presumably "right set theory" requires correctly modeling the universe. If that's what you're saying, then I've no idea what you have in mind as a "right foundation for math", because any formal system (with decidable proof validity) that interprets arithmetic will suffer from the same incompleteness.